# How to implement auto-renewable subscription in iOS with offline Mode?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, youtube, subscription

We need to implement an Auto-renewable subscription for iOS app with offline mode, Once user have subscribe the application after that we need to provide the offline content for particular time period. In this case user no need to enter the online, So how to validate the time expiry date  in offline and need to prevent the time changes in settings by user? How they are handle this kind of situations in Youtube - RED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app runs the first time, store the current data and time in the keychain. Next time the app is launched compare the current date and time with that stored in the keychain.

If it is later then update the stored time.

If it is earlier or the subscription has expired then display a message asking the user to go online and validate their subscription.

You should also update the stored date and time when the app enters the background and check it when the app enters the foreground.

Once they are online you can check the date and time against a server and invalidate/renew their subscription status as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is the one year subscription model - User purchase the subscription and we store the date in the keychain after that user wouldn't open the app for one year. Again they open the app with older date(within the subscription period). But their date is future of our stored date and then easily user hack the application.

Comment: it seems like a lot of trouble to go to, to not use your app for a year and then change their date and time while remaining offline.

Comment: Could you help me on this

Comment: If they are that determined there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Do you have any idea about youtube red?

Comment: No idea. I imagine they would something similar to what I described. Most people are not going to go to the trouble of keeping their device offline and messing up their clock for $13 and as soon as the user wants any new content they have to online and that means youtube can check device time vs server time and invalidate the subscription

Comment: really Thanks @Paulw11. Yes you are correct but it depends on the Country. $13 is very big in some country and really we have the fear about content is in server

Comment: Well, perhaps you can require the user to go online every 3 months to limit the risk, but if people want to steal they will. You can make it harder, but you don't want to annoy legitimate users. Consider all of the difficulty things like css or hdcp cause for legitimate purchase of DVDs etc and it does nothing to prevent piracy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117902/discussion-between-ram-and-paulw11).